# Oracle 10g - Using max on date column that is both partition and index

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table that is both partitioned by and indexed on a `DATE` column `d_dly_label`.

I'm trying to understand the impact of this on `max(d_dly_label)`.  Why does it produce different values for the below two queries:

Query 1:

```
select 
  max(d_dly_label) 
from 
  ECP.TSPT105
where 
  d_dly_label <= to_date('12/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
--result: 13/JUL/14
```

Query 2:

```
select 
  max(d_dly_label) 
from 
  ECP.TSPT105
where 
  d_dly_label <= to_date('12/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  and d_dly_label >= to_date('12/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') - 1;
--result: 11/JUN/15
```

How does adding *more* conditions to the where clause result in a *higher* `max(d_dly_label)`?

---

UPDATE:  I've grabbed the DDL from SQL Developer and cut it down into a short example that replicates the issue.

```
drop table tmp_105_copy;

CREATE TABLE tmp_105_copy
(
  D_DLY_LABEL DATE NOT NULL 
)
PARTITION BY LIST (D_DLY_LABEL) 
(
  PARTITION JUL2014_13 VALUES (TO_DATE(' 2014-07-13 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) 
  , PARTITION JUN2015_11 VALUES (TO_DATE(' 2015-06-11 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) 
);

CREATE INDEX tmp_I1_TSPT105 ON tmp_105_copy(D_DLY_LABEL ASC) 
LOCAL 
(
  PARTITION JUL2014_13 
, PARTITION JUN2015_11 
);

insert into tmp_105_copy values (to_date('13jul2014','ddmonyyyy'));
insert into tmp_105_copy values (to_date('11jun2015','ddmonyyyy'));

commit;

select 
  max(d_dly_label) 
from 
  tmp_105_copy
where 
  d_dly_label <= to_date('12/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
-- 13/JUL/14

analyze table tmp_105_copy estimate statistics;  

select 
  max(d_dly_label) 
from 
  tmp_105_copy
where 
  d_dly_label <= to_date('12/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
-- still 13/JUL/14

select 
  max(d_dly_label) 
from 
  tmp_105_copy
where 
  d_dly_label <= to_date('12/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  and d_dly_label >= to_date('12/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') - 1;
--11/JUN/15

select 
  max(to_date(d_dly_label))
from 
  tmp_105_copy
where 
  d_dly_label <= to_date('12/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
-- also 11/JUN/15
```

Comment: Although you say otherwise, this behavior would occur if `d_dly_label` were stored as a string rather than as a `date`.

Comment: It definitely is stored as a date, but in response to your comment I tried adding a date conversion `max(to_date(d_dly_label))`, and it does yield the correct result for both queries (`12/JUN/15`).  Any idea why?

Comment: This sounds like a "wrong results" bug.  Eventually you'll probably need to search for something on support.oracle.com, and there's probably a patch or workaround available.  Before you do that, you need to make a "Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example".  It's a difficult process and can take several hours.  Copy the DDL, data, and queries and reproduce the problem.  Then keep removing things until you find the smallest difference that causes the bug.  Then paste it here, or look it up, or create a Service Request for Oracle Support to look at.

Comment: I raised it with our DBA team and received the following reply: _It’s know bug from oracle, when you are using the max or min function for date data types columns, you should use to_date function on the date derived columns to get  the min  or max value.
For more information please go thru the below link. Thanks

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2143718_

Comment: The referenced oracle community forum post doesn't say anything about a bug -- it says you have to make sure you're using the correct data type.

Comment: Thanks for updating with a good test case!  Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce this in 11.2.0.3, 11.2.0.4, or 12.1.0.2.  If a problem can only be reproduced on 10g your options are very limited.  Oracle doesn't create new patches for 10g, but maybe there is already an existing patch and Oracle can help you find it if you create a service request.  I did a quick search in My Oracle Support but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an indexed field in a table? If statistics are wrong, such incorrect results can appear. You can try to update the statistics of table and check your query again.

Comment: Wrong statistics generally do not cause wrong results.  I've never seen such behavior, although it's possible there's some rare bug that does it in some specific situation.

Comment: I can confirm that `d_dly_label` is an indexed field.  The statistics on the table show that it hasn't been analyzed since `31/MAY/14`, and that `NUM_ROWS` is 0.  While I was checking this I found that `13/JUL/14` is the earliest date in the table and also the value returned when running `select d_dly_label from ecp.tspt105 where rownum = 1;`.  Unfortunately I get a privileges error when trying to `analyze table ecp.tspt105 estimate statistics;` so can't confirm your solution at this stage.

Comment: Table was analyzed by DBA, and the query now returns the correct result!  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Agree with @JonHeller -- this explanation makes no sense at all. Statistics only affect the most efficient execution plan, not the result.

Comment: I had such a problem (when with wrong statistic Oracle give a wrong result query) at 10.2.0.1. Maybe this is a unstable optimizer bug - when Oracle see that in column (in index) has no rows then returning no rows from query, without reading table data. It's just my guess. Not seen that on the newer versions than 11.2.0.4+.

Comment: This implies there is a "wrong" table or index.  Gathering statistics probably just shifted the execution plan to use the correct object.  Which means this problem may still happen in other queries.  You may want to dig deeper to get to the root cause of this problem.  Wrong results bugs can quickly make users lose confidence in their database.

Comment: I was able to replicate the error in a short example - and unfortunately analysing the table does not solve the issue in this small test case, even though it did "fix" the issue on the production table.